# After upgrading Solr 4.10 to 6.3 the search stopped working

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-oscar

I got a task to upgrade `Solr`, hovewer never worked with `Solr` before.
Currently I have the next stack: Django 1.9.12 + Oscar 1.3 + Solr 6.3.0 + Haystack 2.5.1

I have a generated schema by `Haystack`, put it in the `managed-schema` file and modified a bit according to StackOverflow's answers, because `Solr` did not want to start.
Now I have Solr which starts, but can not find anything via site's search field (hovewer with Solr 4.10 the search worked as expected without any problems).

In `solrconfig.xml` in the section below:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
</lst>
```

I tried to add:

```
<str name="df">text</str>
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
```

After that the search partially started to work.

Few examples:

1. there is such item `INTEL Pentium G3260 (CM8064601482506)`, the search works just with `INTEL Pentium` or `CM8064601482506`. If I want to find `INTEL Pentium G3260` or `Pentium G3260` or `INTEL G3260` or `G3260` - no results.
2. `Search string:` AMD a8-6500;
   `Result:` Nothing to show (no results) -> should find AMD a8-6500
3. `Search string:` AMD;
   `Result:` Shows all AMD products -> as expected

If I change `<str name="q.op">AND</str>` to `<str name="q.op">OR</str>`:

1. `Search string:` AMD a8-6500; `Result:` AMD A8-6500 shows all AMD and
   A8-6500 -> should find just AMD a8-6500
2. `Search string:` a8-6500; `Result:` AMD A8-6500 (AD650BOKA44HL) and
   INTEL Core™ i5 6500 -> should find just AMD a8-6500

My current [solrconfig.xml](https://github.com/TitanFighter/temp/blob/master/solrconfig.xml) and [managed-schema](https://github.com/TitanFighter/temp/blob/master/managed-schema) at GitHub.

As the index field currently I use `EdgeNgramField`, i.e:

```
from haystack import indexes

class ProductIndexes(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
            document=True, use_template=True,
            template_name='search/indexes/cpu/item_text.txt')
```

How to fix\normalize searching?

---

**Update 1:**
Warnings at the Dashboard's logging page

```
[default] default search field in schema is text. WARNING: Deprecated,&#8203; please use 'df' on request instead.
[default] query parser default operator is AND. WARNING: Deprecated,&#8203; please use 'q.op' on request instead.
```

can be fixed by removing

```
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

from `managed-schema` file

**Update 2:**
Based on Socratees's answer, here is the final changes:

1. `indexes.EdgeNgramField` in the next code:

   `class ProductIndexes(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
       text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
              document=True, use_template=True,
              template_name='search/indexes/cpu/item_text.txt')`

   is changed to `indexes.CharField`.
2. As I have other fields with `indexes.CharField`, in `managed-schema` I found, that these fields use type `text_en`, and replace `fieldType name="text_en"` from:

```html
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
      -->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

which is generated by `haystack`, to:

```html
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

3. In `sorlconfig.xml` the code:

```html
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

changed to:

```html
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="q.op">AND</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to find INTEL Pentium G3260 or Pentium G3260 or INTEL G3260 or G3260 - no results.

This is related to how a field analyzed & tokenized. Refer documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers).

Tokenization using ClassicTokenizerFactory will behave like this:
input: "Please, email john.doe@foo.com by 03-09, re: m37-xq."
output: "Please", "email", "john.doe@foo.com", "by", "03-09", "re", "m37-xq"

Tokenization using solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory will behave like this:
input: "babaloo"
output: "ba", "bab", "baba", "babal"

In schema.xml, you can define a new fieldtype, or update the existing one like so:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Play around and see which one fits your scenario. You might also want to look at how the query you give is normalized. But this is a good point to start.

Answer (score 0):

when you use q.op in the solr request. "q.op" request parameter takes precedence over this.

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

example query with q.op parameter:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q.op=AND&q=for ipod&wt=json
```

Comment: I understand this, but how to fix\remove warnings at this page: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging?